# R - count values in multiple columns by group

Tags: r

I have some data:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c('lapse','gone','active','lapse','lapse','active','active','active','gone'),
                 v2 = c('gone','gone','active','lapse','active','lapse','active','lapse','lapse'),
                 v3 = c('gone','gone','gone','gone','active','active','lapse','lapse','lapse'),
                 v4 = c('active','gone','lapse','gone','lapse','gone','lapse','active','lapse'))
```

I need to count the observations in each column grouped by 'lapse','gone' and 'active'.
I need it to look like this:

```
   group     v1     v2     v3     v4
1  lapse     3      4      3      4
2  gone      2      2      4      3
3  active    4      3      2      2
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, we can `gather` the data into long format, `count` the frequency and then `spread` the data to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(key, value) %>%
  count(key, value) %>%
  spread(key, n, fill = 0)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  value     v1    v2    v3    v4
#  <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 active     4     3     2     2
#2 gone       2     2     4     3
#3 lapse      3     4     3     4
```

---

With the new version of `tidyr`, `gather` and `spread` have been replaced by `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` respectively. So the above can be done as

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = names(df)) %>%
  count(name, value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, however when applied to my data it reorganises the columns.  Do you have any idea why this would happen?

Comment: @nogbad you can try to convert the column names to factors. Try `df %>%
  gather(key, value) %>%
  mutate(key = factor(key, levels = unique(key))) %>%
  count(key, value) %>%
  spread(key, n)
`

Comment: Thank you, that's very useful

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
table(stack(df))

        ind
values   v1 v2 v3 v4
  active  4  3  2  2
  gone    2  2  4  3
  lapse   3  4  3  4
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `melt/dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(as.matrix(df)), value ~ Var2)
#   value v1 v2 v3 v4
#1 active  4  3  2  2
#2   gone  2  2  4  3
#3  lapse  3  4  3  4
```

---

Or an option in `base R`

```
table(names(df)[col(df)], unlist(df))
```