# Counting missing data in multiple columns grouped by day in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to count, by day, the missing data (NA's) existing in one column where such is also is missing in another.

Here is my reproducible example:

```
T1 <- data.table (
  Date = c("12-Feb-21", "12-Feb-21","13-Feb-21", "13-Feb-21","13-Feb-21","14- 
     Feb-21","15-Feb-21","15-Feb-21","15-Feb-21", "15-Feb-21"), 
    A = c("ABC", NA, "GHI", "GHI", "JKL", "JKL", "MNO", NA, "DEF", NA),
    B = c(100, NA, 300, NA, 400, 405, 500, NA, 450, NA),
    C = c("O", "O", NA, "C", "O", NA, "C", "C", "O", "C")
)
```

Using my example, I would be looking for the following:

```
Tx <- data.table (
  Date = c("12-Feb-21", "13-Feb-21", "14-Feb-21", "15-Feb-21"),
  A.and.B = c(1, 0, 0, 2 )
)
```

I have looked at several other examples, the closest being:
[R - count values in multiple columns by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57270567/r-count-values-in-multiple-columns-by-group)
but I cannot get this to work.
Other examples are older (eg using plyr instead of dplyr) or not using R

Here's my unsuccessful attempt:

```
T2 <- T1 %>%
  group_by (Data) %>%
  summarize (A.not.B = sum(is.na(T1$A)) & sum(is.na(T1$B)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
T1 %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  mutate(count = ifelse(is.na(A) & is.na(B),1,0)) %>% 
  summarize(A.not.B = sum(count))
```

This gives us:

```
       Date A.and.B
1 12-Feb-21       1
2 13-Feb-21       0
3 14-Feb-21       0
4 15-Feb-21       2
```

A note: your example used `data.table` instead of `data.frame`. I'm not sure if this is intentional, but it can be confusing. `data.frame` is a `base R` object, and `data.table` is specific to the R package named `data.table`.

Here is the slightly modified data I used:

```
T1 <- data.frame(Date = c("12-Feb-21", "12-Feb-21","13-Feb-21", "13-Feb-21","13-Feb-21","14-Feb-21","15-Feb-21","15-Feb-21","15-Feb-21", "15-Feb-21"), 
    A = c("ABC", NA, "GHI", "GHI", "JKL", "JKL", "MNO", NA, "DEF", NA),
    B = c(100, NA, 300, NA, 400, 405, 500, NA, 450, NA),
    C = c("O", "O", NA, "C", "O", NA, "C", "C", "O", "C"))
```

Comment: #Matt, thanks for the solution.  Yes, I am aware that my example used a `data.table`.   I am wondering about your comment about confusion.  Would you mind help further by explaining?